# Krita: Clean up image

Tags: scanner, svg, vector-drawings, vector

How do you clean up a line drawing that you scanned?  The main issue is that the lines come in rather pixelated.  I know that there are methods to make selections by pixel color within Krita but I don't know what to do after that.

The main problem I have is that I am following a step-by-step tutorial that leverages Krita's auto colorization feature (which seems really profound and useful) but my scanned image is too dirty.

Full disclosure, I would appreciate it if someone could do this image for free please but also write down all the steps they used to get the image cleaned (the next step is to probably make it vector)?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Does it have to be Krita? I have a few ideas, but not in Krita.

Comment: Ask on Krita Forums instead. https://krita-artists.org/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, this is not about a question for Ubuntu OS, but I try to answer what I should do with this. It depends on your definition of 'clean up' but I take it as 'less noise draft'. Then you should load this image into `gimp` or something that can manipulate it well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open image by `GIMP`

Select Colors > Brightness-Contrast

[image: brightness-contrast_window]

Then drag the slider into really high contrast and low brightness. Like this.

Then you get an image like before-after:

[image: before-after]

Now no graduation is visible and easy to erase and draw lines useful/unnecessary. But I don't do it, I don't know which ones you want to keep them. After this operation, you can paint easier than before.